# Why subspace of a compact space not compact

Tags: general-topology

In topology, the compact set conveys the idea that all points are not too "separated", since how separated is determined by the topology of the space, so we can roughly say for a compact space, each open set contain many points ( the discrete topology is not compact since some open sets like single point is too small which makes separated). However, the subspace of a compact space maynot be compact, but the volume of open sets of subspace topology is same as  that of the whole space, which really confuses me.

---

I know what I say is far from rigorous, I just want to know if my thinking of compact set is correct or not and if my thinking is correct, why subspace of a compact space not compact

Comment: You are trying to describe compactness locally (in terms of points), while compactness is not a local property.

Comment: Compact=bounded+closed. If a subspace is not closed, then this subspace is not compact

Comment: @Mr.Newman: Be careful. "Compact=bounded+closed" is not even correct in most metric spaces. It *is* correct in $\Bbb R^n$ with the standard metric.

Comment: @TedShifrin pardon:)

Comment: @89085731 $\Bbb R$ has as many open subsets as $[0,1]$, so your argumet by "number of open subsets" does not make much sense to me.

Comment: @G.Sassatelli here number of open sets is not a correct way to discribe the problem, I want to say each open set just contain little points, such as discrete topology, which makes points separate

Comment: @G.Sassatelli I edit my question

Answer (score 3):

It looks like your intuition is incorrect, perhaps due a wrong interpretation of the definition of a compact set. A space is *compact* if each of its open covers has a finite subcover. Unfortunately, this property is not preserved for subspaces, even if you remove only one point of a compact set. For instance, the space $[0,1]$ is compact, but $]0,1]$ is not compact. To see this, consider the open sets $0_n = {]{1 \over n}, 1]}$ for $n >1$. They form a cover of $]0,1]$, but you cannot extract a finite subcover. You may also observe that each $0_n$ "contains many points", but still, not enough to be able to produce a finite cover of $]0,1]$.

Let me also correct a minor detail. Contrary to your claim, a topological set can sometime be compact for the discrete topology: this happens if and only if the set is finite.